# serialEvent1 on cc3200 energia

Tags: texas-instruments

I'm trying to receive data in serial1 on CC3200 launchpad and send the data to serial0 for serial monitor. In my code, serialEvent1 don't work. Anyone has a solution for this? What is wrong, please?

**Update from comments**

I expect to receive data in serial1 and write this data to serial0 for read in serial monitor. I am unable to receive data using the serialEvent1 function. When I put the routine reception inside the loop, I can receive the data. But with the serialEvent1 function does not work. Sorry for the bad english, I hope it has become clear now.

```
String inputString = ""; // a string to hold incoming data
boolean stringComplete = false; // whether the string is complete

void setup()
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(1200);
  Serial1.begin(1200);
  pinMode(GREEN_LED,INPUT);

  // reserve 200 bytes for the inputString:
  inputString.reserve(200); 

}

void loop()
{
  // print the string when a newline arrives:
  if (stringComplete) {
    Serial.println(inputString); 
    // clear the string:
    inputString = "";
    stringComplete = false;
  }
}

/*
  SerialEvent occurs whenever a new data comes in the
  hardware serial RX. This routine is run between each
  time loop() runs, so using delay inside loop can delay
  response. Multiple bytes of data may be available.
*/
void serialEvent1() {

  while (Serial1.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char) Serial1.read(); 
    // add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;
    // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
    // so the main loop can do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n') {
    stringComplete = true;
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "don't work"? What´s the expected behaviour and what's the current behaviour?

Comment: I'm sorry for the poor explanation. I expect to receive data in serial1 and write this data to serial0 for read in serial monitor. I am unable to receive data using the serialEvent1 function. When I put the routine reception inside the loop, I can receive the data. But with the serialEvent1 function does not work. Sorry for the bad english, I hope it has become clear now.